# Different proxy code to upgrade smart contract and reentrancy attacks

Tags: reentrant-attacks, proxy-contracts, contract-upgrading

I am trying to upgrade smart contract in ethereum. I found that proxy pattern can help me with this. In the openzeppelin docs, I should add the following code in `fallback` function in my contract:

```
assembly {
  let ptr := mload(0x40)

  // (1) copy incoming call data
  calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)

  // (2) forward call to logic contract
  let result := delegatecall(gas, _impl, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
  let size := returndatasize

  // (3) retrieve return data
  returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

  // (4) forward return data back to caller
  switch result
  case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
  default { return(ptr, size) }
}
```

It seems that I should forward call and retrieve the return data. However, in some contracts, they just upgrade the contract with code like this:

```
/**
     * Resolves asset implementation contract for the caller and forwards there transaction data,
     * along with the value. This allows for proxy interface growth.
     */
    function () payable {
        _getAsset().__process.value(msg.value)(msg.data, msg.sender);
    }
```

I have two questions:

1. Can the second code also upgrade the smart contract?
2. I think add the first code in `fallback` function in my contract can lead to reentrancy attack, is it true?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two ways to make a contract upgradeable.

- First one uses DELEGATECALL opcode. It doesn't change msg.sender. It has to use assembly to recover returned value. They have some limitations that you have to know before using them https://blog.openzeppelin.com/the-transparent-proxy-pattern/, https://blog.openzeppelin.com/proxy-patterns/.
- Second uses regular CALL opcode. It changes msg.sender so code has to accomodate for that. It doesn't support getters functions because it ignores the returned value.

Neither option provide a protection against reentrancy attacks, it is up to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My understanding before is that the difference depends on whether I need the return value. I will dig it again.